# Game in Pythonista App

Tags: python, beginner, game, python-3.x

I've written this Wack-a-mole like game on my iPad in the app Pythonista. Keeping that in mind, it uses a different graphic interface from the one I have usually seen used, Tkinter. I'm a beginner and this is my first major project, so any tips on how to code more efficiently and improve this program would be greatly appreciated.

```
import random
import ui
from time import sleep
import console
import sys


#turn button to "on" state
def turn_on(sender):
    sender.title = 'on'
    sender.tint_color = ('yellow')

#reverts button to off state    
def turn_off(sender):
    sender.title = 'off'
    sender.tint_color = 'light blue'

#briefly turns button to "on" state then reverts button to       original     state   
def blink(sender):
     turn_on(sender)
     sleep(.5)
     turn_off(sender)

#When the button is tapped, it reverses the current state of the button
def button_tapped(sender):
     turn_off(sender)

#Describes game
def game_Description():
    console.alert("Game objective:", 'Click the button to turn the   light off before the next light turns on', "Ready")

#Pops up when user loses game           
def game_Over_Alert():
    play_Again = console.alert('Game Over!','','Play Again?')
    return play_Again

#Checks to see if all lights are off    
def check_Lights():
    if button.title == 'off':
        if button2.title == 'off':
            if button3.title == 'off':
                if button4. title == 'off':
                        return True

#Turns off all lights
def all_Off():
    turn_off(button)
    turn_off(button2)
    turn_off(button3)
    turn_off(button4)

#Increase score by 1 and display
def increase_Score(x):
    x += 1
    score.title = 'Score: %d' % x
    return x

#setting UI and buttons     
view = ui.View()
view.name = 'Light Panel'
view.background_color = 'black'

button = ui.Button(title = 'off')   
button.center = (view.width*.2, view.height*.5)
button.flex = 'LRTB'
button.action = button_tapped
view.add_subview(button)

button2 = ui.Button(title = 'off')
button2.center = (view.width*.4, view.height*.5)
button2.flex = 'LRTB'
button2.action = button_tapped
view.add_subview(button2)

button3 = ui.Button(title = 'off')
button3.center = (view.width*.6, view.height*.5)
button3.flex = 'LRTB'
button3.action = button_tapped
view.add_subview(button3)

button4 = ui.Button(title = 'off')
button4.center = (view.width*.8, view.height*.5)
button4.flex = 'LRTB'
button4.action = button_tapped
view.add_subview(button4)

scoreCount = 0

score = ui.Button(title = 'Score: 0')
score.center = (view.width*.5, view.height*.75)
score.flex = 'LRTB'
view.add_subview(score)


#Set up display
view.present('sheet')

#Runs the game and handles the function
def play_Game():

    scoreCount = 0
    speed = 2.55
    game_Description()
    random.seed() 
    while check_Lights():
     x = random.randint(0,3)
        if x == 0:
            turn_on(button)
        elif x == 1:
            turn_on(button2)
        elif x == 2:
            turn_on(button3)
        else:
            turn_on(button4)
        scoreCount = increase_Score(scoreCount)
        sleep(speed)
        if speed >= 1.5:
        speed-= .07


    if game_Over_Alert():
        all_Off()
        play_Game()

play_Game() 
view.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Great debut. While I don't have much Python experience, I can suggest that you look up PEP8 and make sure you're abiding by that, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some general tips and guidelines:

- *Do read the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guide* – Loads of good information in that one
- *Use docstring, not comments for functions* – Docstrings will possibly show up in your IDE when you hover or read documentation on functions, so move your function comments to docstrings like this:

  ```
  def turn_on(sender):
      """Switch button to 'on' state."""
      ...
  ```
- *Allow vertical space between functions* – Between functions it is recommended to add two new lines, which helps separate the functions, and allows for using single new lines within functions to group code statements there.
- *Be consistent in naming* – You vary your function naming style from `button_tapped()` to `game_Description()`. I would strongly suggest to be consistent in naming (and other style aspect as well), and the most pythonic way for functions is `snake_case`.
- *Switch to new style string formatting* – Instead of the `%` operator, you are better of using `'Score: {}'.format(x)`. The former is depreceated, and might be removed in the future.
- *Don't intermix top level code and functions* – You have a section of top level code before the `play_game()` (aka `play_Game()`), which is kind of hidden. A really good advice is to *not* have any top level code besides the following at the bottom of the file:

  ```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
  ```

  That is group most of the top level code in a `main()` function, and gather the view initialisation in another function. (Not quite sure how this works in Pythonista, but alternatively, you'll have a single call to `main()` at the top level.)
- *Don't use global variables* – If possible, it is always better to pass values to functions, instead of using them globally. When restructuring into a view initialisation function, this introduces possibly a new concept of returning multiple values from a function (see code below)
- **Feature:** *Your code always increases score, tapped or not* – Your current code always gives you a increase in score, independent on whether you actually tapped anything or not. If however you didn't tap anything, you'll get a false test on the `check_lights()` test. This is kind of hiding the game logic. I'd move the test around a little, to increase understanding of game logic.
- *Indentation errors in presented code* – I'm surprised no-one commented on this yet, but the code as presented doesn't work, there is a faulty indentation on the `x = random.randint(0, 3)` line, and likewise on the `speed -= .07` line. Both lines should be indented. A trick to remember for next post here on Code Review is to mark the entire code block (when editing your question/answer, and hit <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>. (Do **not** edit the code now, though, as you've gotten some answers)
- *Reorganise buttons into a list* – The other answers has touched upon this already, but to take it one step further, you could use a list holding all of your buttons, and this would simplify much of your logic.
- *Include the 0 before floats* – It is not neccessary, and is a minor detail, but I recommend keeping the `0` in front of floats. That is `0.07`, instead of `.07`. (I kept misreading it as `0.7`, and didn't quite see the use of increasing the speed twice before stopping the speed increase... )

Implementing all of these changes (and removing the increase score function, as it kind of hid a main concept of the game) we arrive at the following code:

```
import random
import ui
from time import sleep
import console
import sys


def turn_on(button):
    """Turn button to "on" state."""
    button.title = 'on'
    button.tint_color = ('yellow')


def turn_off(button):
    """Reverts button to off state."""
    button.title = 'off'
    button.tint_color = 'light blue'


def blink(button):
    """Briefly turns switches button state "on" and then "off"."""
    turn_on(button)
    sleep(.5)
    turn_off(button)


def button_tapped(button):
    """When the button is tapped, it turns the button "off"."""
    turn_off(button)


def game_description():
    """Describe game objective in alert box."""
    console.alert("Game objective:", 
       "Click the button to turn the   light off before the next light turns on", 
       "Ready")


def game_over_alert():
    """Alert box stating game over, and asking for a new game."""

    return console.alert('Game Over!','','Play Again?')


def check_lights(buttons):
    """Check if all buttons are turned off."""
    return all(button.title == 'off' for button in buttons)


def all_off(buttons):
    """Turn off all buttons."""
    for button in buttons:
        turn_off(button)


def add_button(view, width_percentage, height_percentage,
               button_action=None, title='off'):
    """Adds a button positioned by percentages, with given title."""

    button = ui.Button(title)
    button.center = (view.width * width_percentage, view.height * height_percentage) 
    button.flex = 'LRTB'
    button.action = button_action
    view.add_subview(button)
    return button


def initialise_view():
    """Initialise view, and return view and buttons."""

    view = ui.View()

    # Default settings for view

    view = ui.View()
    view.name = 'Light Panel'
    view.background_color = 'black'

    # Create "mole" buttons
    mole_buttons = [add_button(view, 0.2 * (i + 1), 0.5,
                               button_action=button_tapped) for i in range(4)]

    score_button = add_button(view, 0.5, 0.75, 'Score: 0')

    return view, mole_buttons, score_button


def play_game(view, mole_buttons, score_button):
    """Main game loop. Handles game, and restarting of game."""

    score_count = 0
    speed = 2.55
    game_description()
    random.seed() 

    while True:
        turn_on(mole_buttons[random.randint(0, 3)])

        # Allow player to wack a mole        
        sleep(speed)

        # Check if they hit the mole, that is check all lights are off
        if check_lights(mole_buttons):
            score_count += 1
            score_button.title = 'Score: {}'.format(score_count)
        else:
            # They failed hitting the mole
            break

        # Change speed a little
        if speed >= 1.5:
            speed-= 0.07


    if game_over_alert():
        all_off()
        play_game(view, mole_buttons, score_button)


def main():
    view, mole_buttons, score_button = initialise_view()
    view.present('sheet')

    play_game(view, mole_buttons, score_button)

    view.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I haven't installed Pythonista, yet, so I'm not able to test this code, but hopefully it should work nicely.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps quite a lot. I actually looked back over my code the next day and integrated the changes the others suggested as while as some of my own. I did put the buttons in a list, but the way I did it is much less efficient than your way. I knew that the fact that my score increased regardless of whether the played won or lost the round was a problem, but I couldn't think up a way to fix it with out recoding much of much of the program (and I was tired so I wasn't able to attempt it at the time). Again, this all helps very much, and I am working on improving my coding.

Answer (score 3):

Please follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide.

---

This function returns either `True` or `None`:

```
def check_Lights():
    if button.title == 'off':
        if button2.title == 'off':
            if button3.title == 'off':
                if button4. title == 'off':
                    return True
```

Make it a proper boolean. And, instead of the arrow shaped writing style, you can rewrite this as a single boolean expression, for example:

```
return button1.title == 'off' and button2.title == 'off' and ...
```

As [@Caridorc](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/54718/caridorc) pointed out in a comment, you can do even better:

```
return all(b.title == 'off' for b in (button, button2, button3, button4))
```

---

Don't repeat yourself. The way you create and add new buttons is very repetitive. Create a utility function to reduce the duplication, for example:

```
def add_new_button(wcoeff, hcoeff):
    button = ui.Button(title = 'off')   
    button.center = (view.width * wcoeff, view.height * hcoeff)
    button.flex = 'LRTB'
    button.action = button_tapped
    view.add_subview(button)
    return button
```

Comment: Even less duplication: `return all(b.title == 'off' for b in (button, button2 ...))`

Comment: I've been teaching myself Python, so I've never been told exactly how to style it, so I'll learn to follow PEP8, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**`random.choice`**

```
 x = random.randint(0,3)
    if x == 0:
        turn_on(button)
    elif x == 1:
        turn_on(button2)
    elif x == 2:
        turn_on(button3)
    else:
        turn_on(button4)
```

Becomes:

```
 turn_on( random.choice( (button, button2, button3, button4) ) )
```

The second is more coincise and readable.